# Is it possible to search for objects in Photos?

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, photosframework, photolibrary

do you know if it's possible to use the `Photos` Framework to search for specific photo categories (auto-generated by Apple's ML) in iOS 10?

For example, I'd like to get all the photos with a car in them.

Comment: you need to check the All Photos metadata. If you get that kind of category fild then yes you can..:)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any reference regarding this in Apple developer documentation. I have a feeling that this Photos app inbuilt feature we see in iOS10, hasn't been made public facing yet.
I did find this article covering the different categories someone found out: [Photos ML categories](https://writekay.github.io/Updated-Photos-App-Recongnizes-Thousands-of-Objects/)

Hopefully, in WWDC this June we will have more access.

Kind regards,
Mukund

Comment: Still not possible in iOS11?